# Can an EC2 instance be registered with multiple ECS clusters?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a single ASG that I'd like to use for capacity for multiple ECS clusters. Is this possible  ? I see that we can only specify a single ECS cluster in the ENV variables for ECS agent https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible: partly because of your comment on the agent only being aware of one cluster, but also operability issues: the clusters would be required to be aware of each other and place containers collaboratively.

Have you considered running the different services on a single cluster, rather than managing multiple clusters? I mean, you are already planning on sharing the EC2 resource. Be mindful of port mappings.